# Prove using Propositional logic laws | Killer question!

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm stuck on this for 2 hours. Can't start with R.H.S also due to less no of variables.

> Q. $(p \land q \land \neg r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land \neg r) \equiv p \land \neg r$

**Here I started:**

$(p \land q \land \neg r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land \neg r)$

$p \land (q \land \neg r) \lor p \land (\neg q \land \neg r)$ **using Associative Law**

$p \land (\neg q \land \neg r) \lor p \land (q \land \neg r)$ **using Distributive Law**

What else can we do with it? Any idea? Much appreciated.

Comment: You have to apply [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) to get : $(p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬r) ≡ (p ∧ ¬r) ∨ (¬q ∧ q)$ and then use the fact that $(¬q ∧ q) ≡ F$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the answer, but how it becomes this (p∧¬r) ∨ (¬q∧q) when I think it should have been p ∧ (¬q∧¬r) ∨ p∧(q∧¬r) as I wrote in the question? Distributive Law is very simple, but it is acting very complex in this question. Can you clarify in parallel what is what in question (p∧q∧¬r)∨(p∧¬q∧¬r) according to this distributive law. p ∨ ( q ∧ r ) ≡ ( p ∨ q ) ∧ ( p ∨ r ) Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have only to use more parentheses... $[(p∧¬r)∧q]∨[(p∧¬r)∧¬q]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$(p \land q \land \neg r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land \neg r) \equiv p \land \neg r \iff (p\land \neg r)(q\lor \neg q)$$
by invoking the distributive law.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how it becomes this **(p∧¬r)(q∨¬q)** when it should have been p ∧ (¬q∧¬r) ∨ p∧(q∧¬r) as I wrote in the question? Distributive Law is very simple, but it is acting very complex in this question. Can you clarify in parallel what is what in question (p∧q∧¬r)∨(p∧¬q∧¬r) according to this distributive law. **p ∨ ( q ∧ r ) ≡ ( p ∨ q ) ∧ ( p ∨ r )** Thanks a lot.

Comment: $p\wedge \sim r$ appears in both operands.

Comment: Thanks so it means that we can change the variables (p, q etc) places if there are any combination of ∧ , v, biconditional operations in between to solve the answer except if it is conditional operation. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: Mais oui, c'est vrai.......